# What is the openssl equivalent of using java's KeyPairGenerator?

Tags: java, encoding, cryptography, rsa, key-pair

Firstly I tried to ask this on security -- I got some upvotes but it seems it has had no answer for a week now. I understand that this is openssl related, however it stems from using a java KeyPairGenerator object so I feel it may be valid for stack overflow. Please see the code below:

I have been using java's KeyPairGenerator in order to generate public/private keys within a program so that I can encrypt and decrypt files(also using java encrypt/decrypt methods). I want to be able to move over to using openssl in order to generate these public private keypairs however I keep getting padding exceptions when I decrypt my files if i used command line generated openssl keys. For example instead of using java's KeyPairGenerator, I try and use openssl to generate keys:

```
openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -outform DEF -pubout -out public.der
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in keypair.pem -outform DER -out private.der
```

Where I try to use the DER files to encrypt/decrypt my files. Ultimately every key format I have tried seems to give me problems.

I'm assuming that this means that the format of the keys in my openssl commands do not match up how java's KeyPairGenerator works. Here is a snippet of my key generating code:

```
public void createPublicPrivateKeys() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    logger.info("Password to encrypt the private key: ");
    String password = in.readLine();
    logger.info("Generating an RSA keypair.");

    // Create an RSA key key pair
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(4096);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

    logger.info("Done generating the keypair.\n");

    // Write public key out to a file
    String publicKeyFilename = "publicKey.der";
    logger.info("Public key filename: " + publicKeyFilename);

    // Get  encoded form of the public key for future usage -- this is X.509 by default.
     byte[] publicKeyBytes = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();

     // Write the encoded public key
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFilename);
     fos.write(publicKeyBytes);
     fos.close();

     String privateKeyFilename = "privateKey.der";
     logger.info("Private key filename: " + privateKeyFilename);

     // Get the encoded form -- PKCS#8 by default.
     byte[] privateKeyBytes = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();

     // Encrypt the password
     byte[] encryptedPrivateKeyBytes = new byte[0];
     try {
         encryptedPrivateKeyBytes = passwordEncrypt(password.toCharArray(), privateKeyBytes);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     fos = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFilename);
     fos.write(encryptedPrivateKeyBytes);
     fos.close();
 }
```

What is the openssl equivalent command line statement of using java's standard KeyPairGenerator? Also note that using outside packages such as bouncy castle is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL commandline `rsa` or `pkcs8` do not generate a keypair; they only convert from one form to another and/or display. For RSA (only), `genrsa` generates a keypair, in OpenSSL's 'legacy' privatekey format which is not (easily) compatible with Java. Your `rsa` and `pkcs8` commands do convert the legacy format to the "X.509" (SPKI) and PKCS#8 DER formats Java prefers. OpenSSL since 1.0.0 also has `genpkey` which generates keys, or where applicable parameters, for all supported asymmetric algorithms including RSA, and defaults to PKCS#8 output.

Your Java code has a `passwordEncrypt` step that is not standard Java and not explained. OpenSSL library supports password-based encryption of PKCS#8 according to that standard if that is what your `passwordEncrypt` does, but most OpenSSL commandline functions don't. 
If you are trying to use the `private.der` of your example in Java which is trying to do any kind of password-based (or other) decryption on it, that won't work because it isn't encrypted; it isn't even in the PKCS#8 structure used for an encrypted key. 
However that error would occur *before* you even try to decrypt any data, or more likely a working key.

Comment: Thank you very much for the knowledgeable reply -- It's pushing me in the right direction. Just for clarification I am attempting to encrypt a file using a password protected public-private key pair. This file will be sent to and from a user which would need to be decrypted on both ends of connection. From my understanding Java does not like password protected key pairs, therefore I am attempting to implement my own means of encrypting and storing the password for later use, by having the user enter in a password. Given the constraints would you be able to recommend anything else?

Comment: I'm considering symmetric encryption for the given task as well, but I'm open to any and all sources of information. Besides using openssl to generate the key pair, using only-java would be the optimal situation for my task.

Comment: @void.massive Java doesn't directly handle encrypted key *files*, but its file-based key *stores* use password-encryption precisely for the purpose of storing keypairs safely. The simplest and very common (hence well-known and understood) way is to use `keytool` to create a keystore -- JKS by default -- with an encrypted generated privatekey *and* a selfsigned/dummy certificate, and then have your programs load that keystore and use either the (password-decrypted) privatekey or the cert/publickey as appropriate. There are other possibilities, but I would try simple first.